# Cannot read property 'sendEth' of undefined, 'sendEth' is function in smart contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-deployment, metamask

Hi I'm trying to interact with an Ethereum smart contract but it is always showing "TypeError : Cannot read property 'sendEth' of undefined" where 'sendEth' is a function in my smart contract

Here is code snippet:

```
function sendEth() {
            var transferEthAddress = "0x0152E36df4fB7587b035fbF5c02A059A0B3b9c38";
            var transferEth = new window.web3.eth.contract(transferEthABI, transferEthAddress);
            transferEth.methods.sendEth().send({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], value: web3js.utils.toWei("0.001","ether")});
        }
        window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
            if (window.ethereum) { // Modern dapp browsers... 
                window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
                try {
                    await ethereum.enable(); // Request account access if needed
                }
                catch (error) {
                    console.log('User denied permission to use their Ethereum account.');
                }
            }
            else if (window.web3) { // Legacy dapp browsers...
                window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
            }
            else { // Non-dapp browsers...
                console.log('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!');
            }
        });
```

Web3 is getting successfully connected to my smart contract as I can see transaction in Metamask but I am unable to access the function, please help!

Here is my contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;
import "./Ownable.sol";
contract demo is Ownable
{
    function sendEth() external payable
    {
        //_owner will have the address of the deployer of contract.
        address _owner = owner();
        _owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your contract code to make it clear. Thanks

Comment: Check value of `transferEth`.  It is probably `null`.

Comment: check value of `transferEth` and let me know where you deploy your contract localy or public test net?

Comment: I have deployed the contract using Remix IDE on Ropsten Test Net.

Comment: I have checked **transferEth**, it is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some typos to fix:

- Capital **C** while calling `contract` function.

`var transferEth = new window.web3.eth.Contract(transferEthABI, transferEthAddress);`

- It is **web3.utils** instead of web3js.utils:

`transferEth.methods.sendEth().send({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], value: web3.utils.toWei("0.001","ether")});`

Lastly, almost all functions from web3 are asynchronous and returning promise, so do not forget to write callback or use async/await syntax.

```
async function sendEth() {
 var transferEthAddress = "0x0152E36df4fB7587b035fbF5c02A059A0B3b9c38";
 var transferEth = await new window.web3.eth.Contract(transferEthABI, transferEthAddress);
 console.log(transferETH);
 await transferEth.methods.sendEth().send({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], value: web3.utils.toWei("0.001","ether")});
        }
```

Also show me the console.log.

I hope it will work, try and let me know if did not work.
Thanks

Comment: I have tried all these things, but it didn't worked for me. I have written callback also, that also didn't worked.

Comment: Can you please, send me your ABI? can you see the sendEth() in ABI?

Comment: https://github.com/imnishant/Transfer-Ethereum/blob/master/transferEth_abi.js          
This is link to abi of this contract.

Comment: And where is yout contract deployed? Local? Or any other test net?

Comment: I have deployed the contract using Remix IDE on Ropsten Test Net.

Comment: Can you call the function from remix? If so try this approach function i added in the answer.

Comment: Yes, I called the function from remix, it is working fine. Below is the link to the output in console.
https://github.com/imnishant/Transfer-Ethereum/blob/master/Screenshot%20from%202019-03-20%2023-29-39.png

Comment: Please help with the issue .

Comment: Anyone please help